# How do I configure my git to set the branch to main instead of master automatically?

Tags: git

Whenever I create a new git init, it automatically names the default branch to master rather than naming it to main.

Answer (score 0):

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-initdefaultBranch

```bash
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```